# How to properly deploy application with SQLCE via click once

Tags: .net, sql-server-ce, logging, nlog

I need NLog to write logs into the sqlce database. Did everything mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6113467/a-sample-configuration-for-nlog-and-sql-server-compact-4-0)(i also add sqlserverce reference via nuget, which after build adds 2 folders to bin(x86 and amd64) with assemblies that are not becoming part of deploy solution, because i cant see them in installed software directory), but the program works fine just on my computer. On any other computer i install my software via clickonce it leaves compact database clean..Are there any steps to properly deploy application with sql server compact?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Worked fine after i added all that DLLs from x86 folder in nuget package directory to my application as links.